# Explanation of Span {x, y, z} = Span {y, z}? Definition of spanning?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

If x is in U, and U = span{y, z}, why is it: then U = span{x, y, z}?

If we start with only y, z, how can we write U = span{x, y, z}? I originally thought that spanning is also about zero redundant vectors. Wouldn't x be a redundant vector?

I tried to get help, and the explanation given to me was: every linear combination of x, y, z can be written as a linear combination of y, z. Maybe it is because of language barrier that I am not understanding this properly, but how can a linear combination be rewritten as a linear combination that doesn't include the vector?

I apologize in advance if my question is unclear, please guide and help me out, I would appreciate it. Right now, I want to understand the definition of spanning, and the explanation given to me.

Comment: *Spanning* sets may certainly contain redundant vectors. *Linearly independent* may not!

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, I understand now! Thank you very much. So in this case, span{x, y, z} is a spanning set and x is indeed redundant. span{y, z} would be the linearly independent one.

Comment: Assuming $y$ and $z$ aren’t parallel, yes. :)

Answer (score 3):

If $x=ay+bz$ and you have a linear combination of $x,y,z$:
$$
w=cx+dy+ez
$$
then
$$
w=c(ay+bz)+dy+ez=(ac+d)y+(bc+e)z
$$
which is a linear combination of just $y$ and $z$.

Adding linear combinations does not modify the span.

Comment: Why is it still span if it includes x? Would x not be redundant then? Thank you for the example, it's beginning to make more sense.

Comment: The span is the set of all linear combinations. It is the smallest set stable under “taking linear combinations “. $x$ was already in the span of $y,z$, so adding it is redundant.

Comment: So for example the span of $x,2x,3x$ is the same as the span of $x$. When you eliminate all redundant vectors you get a basis of the span.